# How to use Keycloak REST API for login using SMS OTP passwordless authentication?

Tags: java, keycloak, redhat, one-time-password

I have modified some SMS OTP Authentication SPI from github and successfully used it for Keycloak Authentication. Then I made a custom flow for browser so that:

1. Username-only form gets the username (May be the mobile number)
2. Sends code to the user mobile
3. Gets the code and authenticates the user

The above works great! Now I need the same in REST API. When using documents, they say we have to set grant type. But the grant type is password in all examples.

```
curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/apiman/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
 --data-urlencode 'client_id=account' \
 --data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
 --data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
 --data-urlencode 'scope=openid' \
 --data-urlencode 'username=otp'
```

BTW: I have added direct grant bindings same as form bindings (which works great) with no luck. How can I use REST API for login flow same as form authentication?

Comment: Direct access grant supports `otp` parameter (for builtin TOTP). It is a question how it is supported in your custom SPI, especially when you don't know code before auth request.

Comment: @JanGaraj The problem is that TOTP is after username/password login, (2FA) but my case is password-less authentication, that is the code is used instead of password.

Comment: @JanGaraj BTW currently the code is sent via SMS but I guess the Keycloak does not know to do afterward

Comment: that's exactly what I wrote "especially when you don't know code before auth request"

Comment: did you find a solution???